# sequential** and **$US$-space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called a $US$-space provided that each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

A topological space is called a sequential space if a set
$A \subset X$ is closed if and only if together with any sequence it contains all its limits.

> Is the **product of two $US$-space** ( $US \times US$) , also $US$-space?
>
> Is there relation between **sequential** and **$US$-space**?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be an US-space, let $\bigl((x_n,y_n)\bigr)$ be a sequence in $X^2$, converging to $(x,y)$. If $(x_n, y_n) \to (x',y')$, then, as the projections $\pi_i \colon X^2 \to X$ are continuous, we have $x_n \to x,x'$, $y_n \to y,y'$. As $X$ is US, we have $x=x'$ and $y=y'$, so $X^2$ is US.

There are sequential spaces, which aren't US, for example, any set $X$ with at least two elements with the indiscrete topology. This is not US, as any sequence converges to any point, but sequential as the only closed sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$.

There are US spaces, which aren't sequential, for example $\omega_1+1$ in its order topology. $\omega_1 + 1$ is Hausdorff, so US, but it is not sequential, as the non-closed $\omega_1 \subseteq \omega_1 + 1$ is sequentially closed.